# bootstrap navbar centered in footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center ul tag in div
My Html code

```
<footer>
     <div class="wrap">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav social">
           <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Li</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">TW</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">You</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</footer>
```

and the css

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    height: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 6;
}
footer .wrap{
    margin: 10px auto;

}
.social{
    width: 250px;
}
```

I post screenshot of my actualy situation: 
[image: I want to margin it into center of wrap]

P.S: i do it responsive, and sorry for my english

Comment: here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/50gkxjd6/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can cancel float on `navbar-nav` element and then center it with `margin: 0 auto`:

```
.social {
    width: 250px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/dmH6ySgEO5XnwXBbE7gt?p=preview

Comment: can you create jsfiddle? .. maybe i do anything bad

Comment: thanks a lot i find mistake i use margin: 0 auto; on .wrap thanks a lot!

Comment: Also note, that you might probably want to fix media queries styles, because by default you nav menu items will be inline only for resolution > `768px`. In my demo I reset it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj4qsrhw/)

use this html:

```
 <footer>
  <div class="wrap text-center">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav social center-text">
       <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Li</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">TW</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">You</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </footer>
```

add this css:

```
 .nav {
display:inline-block;
float: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are trying to center the text in the div. Therefore you can try `.social: text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this class in the parent `<div>` of the Navbar it automatically splits the margin:

```
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}
```

which in your case would look like:

```
<div class="wrap center">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line to your footer .wrap:

```
footer.wrap {
   text-align: center
}
```

**check the snippet**

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 6;
}
footer .wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
footer ul {
  list-style: none;
}
footer li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav social">
      <li><a href="#">FB</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Li</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">TW</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">You</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mumfordjw/b51jre2b/)